# How to get the error code from requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, python-requests

I sometimes get this error.

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, '현재 연결은 원격 호스트에 의해 강제로 끊겼습니다', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, '현재 연결은 원격 호스트에 의해 강제로 끊겼습니다', None, 10054, None))
```

Since I see the error code 10054, I want to handle this error with error code like this

```
    try:
        result =  requests.get(url=url, **kwargs)
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
        #get the error code from e and then
        if errorcode==10054:
            #do something
```

I tried this at first but it gave me another error that the ChunkedEncodingError object has no arg.

```
    try:
        result =  requests.get(url=url, **kwargs)
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
        errorcode = e.arg[1]
        if errorcode==10054:
            #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
try:
    result =  requests.get(url=url, **kwargs)
except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
    #get the error code from e and then
    if e.errno==10054:
        #do something
```

Comment: Oh! I will try that and let you know soon! Thank you!

Comment: @체라치에 Hi, If this solution worked for you then could you please accept the answer?